# How do you test offchain_index::set?

Tags: offchain-storage, unit-tests

I have code that writes to offchain_index:

```
offchain_index::set(&my_key, &my_data.encode());
```

However, my unit tests are unable to retrieve the data via:

```
let my_offchain_data = StorageValueRef::persistent(&my_key).get::<MyDataType>();
```

The above returns `None`. According to https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/ocw/indexing/ this is how I should retrieve the data.

If I persist the data using `StorageValueRef::persistent(&my_key).set(&my_data.clone().encode());` I am able to retrieve the data in my unit tests.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the following way:

```
    let mut ext = sp_io::TestExternalities::new_empty();
    ext.execute_with(|| {
        sp_io::offchain_index::set(b"hello", b"world");
    });

    ext.persist_offchain_overlay();
    let offchain_db = ext.offchain_db();
    assert_eq!(
        offchain_db.get(b"hello"),
        Some(b"world".to_vec()),
    );
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you!